# Sugar CRM generating "incorrect" GUIDs

Tags: php, .net, sql-server, guid, sugarcrm

According to [here](http://docs.sugarcrm.com.s3.amazonaws.com/Developer_Guides/Developer_Guide_5.1/DevGuide.1.34.html) Sugar CRM uses GUIDs for PK and FK needs

> By default, Sugar uses globally unique identification values (GUIDs)
>   for primary keys for all database records

However they're not true GUIDs, at least in the sense defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier), as in debugging an issue I got a parsing error (via JSON.NET as it happens, but the same issue would be easily replicable myself)

The offending pseudo-GUID was "7f09zz7d-889a-1x19-825b-54s954665005" which is most certainly not correct.

Looking at the database table, the field that is holding this record is a VARCHAR(36), not a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER. This means that *any* 36 characters can be plonked in there. So far, so good - for Sugar CRM that is.

The issue arises when you try to use this "GUID" from a .NET perspective (e.g. `Guid.Parse()`) or SQL Server using a field actually properly defined as a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER.

This leads to two problems really:

1. How can I make Sugar CRM generate compliant GUIDs? Bearing in mind I learned how to spell PHP about 5 minutes before typing this question. PHP [appears to have](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php) a `com_create_guid` function but I don't know if (or where) Sugar is using it
2. Can anyone recommend a strategy for the existing values that may not conform? Adding a nullable UNIQUEIDENTIFIER column and inserting the values from the existing VARCHAR column and handling the exceptions on a case-by-case basis is about the only way I can think of dealing with it.

Comment: In Sugar 6 you could enter whatever in the ID column, so the backwards compatibility of a VARCHAR column in Sugar 7 is at least necessary there, since they can't all be assumed GUIDs